# SpecFlow NUnit RequiresSTA attribute

Tags: nunit, specflow, apartment-state

I need to have SpecFlow generate NUnit Tests with the RequiresSTA attribute. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autogenerated xxx.feature.cs file has a partial class definition. Simply create an xxxFeature.cs with another partial class that has the attribute on it.